# Creating intervals from time series data

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a **data frame of users and access times**. Access **times** can be **duplicated**.
I am trying to create a **list of users grouped** and named **by** a given **time interval**, e.g. year.

```
timestamp user
1  2013-03-06 01:00:00    1
2  2014-07-06 21:00:00    1
3  2014-07-31 23:00:00    2
4  2014-08-09 17:00:00    2
5  2014-08-14 20:00:00    2
6  2014-08-14 22:00:00    3
7  2014-08-16 15:00:00    3
8  2014-08-19 02:00:00    1
9  2014-12-28 18:00:00    1
10 2015-01-17 17:00:00    1
11 2015-01-22 22:00:00    2
12 2015-01-22 22:00:00    3
13 2015-03-23 15:00:00    4
14 2015-04-05 18:00:00    1
15 2015-04-06 01:00:00    2
```

My **code example** already creates a list of **users grouped by year**.
My problem is that I need to **modify** the **table** in this approach, which becomes a problem with my tables of a **million entries**.

```
test <- structure(list(timestamp = c("2013-03-06 01:00:00", "2014-07-06 21:00:00", 
                                 "2014-07-31 23:00:00", "2014-08-09 17:00:00", "2014-08-14 20:00:00", 
                                 "2014-08-14 22:00:00", "2014-08-16 15:00:00", "2014-08-19 02:00:00", 
                                 "2014-12-28 18:00:00", "2015-01-17 17:00:00", "2015-01-22 22:00:00", 
                                 "2015-01-22 22:00:00", "2015-03-23 15:00:00", "2015-04-05 18:00:00", 
                                 "2015-04-06 01:00:00"), user = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L)), .Names = c("timestamp", "user"
                                                                  ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))

require(lubridate)
#Creating "POSIXct" object from string timestamp
timestamp <- lapply(test$timestamp,
                function(x)parse_date_time(x, "y-m-d H:M:S"))
test$timestamp <- do.call(c,timestamp)
print(class(test$timestamp))

#Adding column for year
test <- cbind(test,sapply(timestamp, function(x)year(x)))
colnames(test)[3]<- "year"

#Creating list of year time intervals for users
intervals <- names(table(test$year))
users <- lapply(intervals, function(x)test[test$year %in% x,"user"])
names(users) <- intervals
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**without timestamps**

treat the `timestamp` as a character. Only works if for every timestap, the first 4 digits represent the year.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
  group_by( user, substr(timestamp,1,4 ) ) %>%
  summarise( )

#    user `substr(timestamp, 1, 4)`
#   <int> <chr>                    
# 1     1 2013                     
# 2     1 2014                     
# 3     1 2015                     
# 4     2 2014                     
# 5     2 2015                     
# 6     3 2014                     
# 7     3 2015                     
# 8     4 2015
```

**dplyr + lubridate**

will extract the year from the timestamp

```
library( dplyr )
library( lubridate )
test %>%
  mutate( timestamp = as.POSIXct( timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" ) ) %>%
  group_by( user, lubridate::year( timestamp ) ) %>%
  summarise( )

# # Groups:   user [?]
#    user `year(timestamp)`
#   <int>             <dbl>
# 1     1              2013
# 2     1              2014
# 3     1              2015
# 4     2              2014
# 5     2              2015
# 6     3              2014
# 7     3              2015
# 8     4              2015
```

**table**

a frequency table is also quickly made

```
table( test$user, substr( test$timestamp, 1, 4 ) )

#   2013 2014 2015
# 1    1    3    2
# 2    0    3    2
# 3    0    2    1
# 4    0    0    1
```

there are any more alternatives... pick one

### edit

if speed is an issue, ty data.table

```
dcast( 
  setDT( test )[, timestamp :=  as.POSIXct( timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" )][, .N, by = list( user, data.table::year(timestamp) )],
  user ~ data.table,
  value.var = "N")

#    user 2013 2014 2015
# 1:    1    1    3    2
# 2:    2   NA    3    2
# 3:    3   NA    2    1
# 4:    4   NA   NA    1
```

Comment: This is the more generic solution - can be easily modified using months, days,...

Answer (score 1):

Another option using the lightning fast `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test) # make `test` a data.frame 'by reference' (no copy is made at all)

test[, j=.(users=list(unique(user))),
       by=.(year=substr(test$timestamp,1,4))] 

   year   users
1: 2013       1
2: 2014   1,2,3
3: 2015 1,2,3,4
```

Again assuming your test$timestamp column is a character vector - otherwise substitute lubridate::year() as needed.

#### Update:

Simple change to show grouping instead by month (just as it was mentioned in a comment):

```
 test[, j=.(users=list(unique(user))),
        by=.(ym=substr(test$timestamp,1,7))] 

        ym users
1: 2013-03     1
2: 2014-07   1,2
3: 2014-08 2,3,1
4: 2014-12     1
5: 2015-01 1,2,3
6: 2015-03     4
7: 2015-04   1,2
```

Or group by day, to help demonstrate how to subset with chaining:

```
test[, j=.(users=list(unique(user))),
       by=.(ymd=substr(test$timestamp,1,11))][ymd>='2014-08-01' & ymd<= '2014-08-21']

           ymd users
1: 2014-08-09      2
2: 2014-08-14    2,3
3: 2014-08-16      3
4: 2014-08-19      1
```

Note for filtering/subsetting, if you are only interested in a subset of dates for a "one off" calculation (and not otherwise saving the whole aggregated set to be stored for other purposes) it will likely be more efficient to do the subset in `i` of `DT[i, j, by]` for the "one off" calculation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use base (stats) function `aggregate()` as follows:

```
aggregate( x = test$user, 
           by = list(year=substr(test$timestamp,1,4)), 
           FUN = unique )
```

Result:

```
  year          x
1 2013          1
2 2014    1, 2, 3
3 2015 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Above working on assumption that your timestamp column is initially just a  character vector exactly as included in your structured example data. In which case you may directly substr out the year with `substr(test$timestamp,1,4)` avoiding the need to first convert to dates.

However, if you have the timestamp column already as a date, simply substitute the `lubridate::year()` function you demonstrated in your attempted solution.

Comment: Agreed this will not be the fastest solution you could possibly obtain. But just curious, as `aggregate()` is actually notably pretty fast could you try it with your data against your original solution and post the times? It would make for an interesting comparison and useful benchmark for others.